# Action bar custom component (a custom switch) is not showing with actionLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I want to make a custom switch in the action bar. This is my menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:autolux="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_notification_switch"
    android:title=""
    android:actionLayout="@layout/notification_switch"
   autolux:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

This is my custom notification switch xml notification_switch.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<Switch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/color"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON"
    android:thumb="@drawable/navigation_switch_selector"
    android:checked="false"
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_notification" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is what I call from my activity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notification_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

But my actionbar does not show my custom switch (or any other component if I put it in the notification_switch.xml). Also I am able to set the main.xml menu as my menu wich only uses an icon and that works. That code is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:autolux="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_filter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        autolux:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong with my custom components. Any help will be appreciated. (additional info is: Min Sdk Version 14, Compile Sdk Version 19, Build Tools Version 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it helps:

remove:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notification_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

then in your `onCreate method`:

```
 ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
 LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
 View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_switch, null);
 mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
 mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

reference:

http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

if you are using `actionBarCompat` use `getSupportActionBar` instead of `getActionBar`